# how to avoid overlapping of barchart using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am new to data science using python . While plotting two different barcharts I got into an problem. This is my code :

```
def compare_groups(field):
if field in less_equal_150_cal.columns:
  less_equal_150_cal[field].plot.bar(color = 'blue',alpha =0.4, title = field )
  more_150_cal[field].plot.bar(color = 'red', alpha =0.4)
else:
    raise ValueError(f"{field} not found")
```

[image]

[image: less_equal_150_cal]The resulting bargraphs are overlapping each other. I want two different bar graphs.

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide a sample data and provide a figure you get.

Comment: Could you add your data as text, not as image? Could you add the code that calls your function?  Do you call `plt.figure()` or similar to create a new figure?

Comment: @JohanC...the last image also contains the way I call it. Should I copy paste the output?

Comment: The recommended way is `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)` and then `less_equal_150_cal[field].plot.bar(..., ax=ax1)` and `more_150_cal[field].plot.bar(..., ax=ax2)`

Comment: The preferred way to add your data is the output of something like `less_equal_150_cal.to_dict(orient='list')` or `less_equal_150_cal.head(10).to_dict(orient='list')`. That way it would be available as runnable code.

Comment: You can use seaborn after adding a new column as a differentiator, e.g. `drinks_df['IsMore'] = drinks_df['Calories'] > 150`, then  `ax = sns.barplot(data=drinks_df, x='Item', y=field, hue='IsMore')` and maybe `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)`